# Making a slideshow in python/tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

this is my first post and I am still a novice in the python world. I am trying to make a GUI application with python/tkinter and I have run into some trouble. I have 2 folders of images, and I need to display a page with some text, then display an image from folder A, then display the same page with text and then display an image from the folder B. I can get those images to show up, but my problem is keeping everything centered and looking good. If I resize the images smaller than the parent frame then there is whitespace around the edges. There is extreme whitespace around the edge of the page with text due to how small the widget is.

Here is a list of the problems I am having:

- Whitespace around edge of widgets smaller than the parent frame.
- Widgets not centered in middle of page.

Here is the code I have for the frame with those problems. I know it is not the cleanest, but I would really appreciate some help if possible.

```
class TrialPage(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent,controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    self.parent = parent
    self.configure(bg='#5B9BD5')
    self.stimFrames = []
    self.evalList = []

    #initialize object to retrieve image paths
    self.trialData = TrialData()

    self.trialStim = [self.trialData.Trial_Stimuli_1,
                        self.trialData.Trial_Stimuli_2,
                        self.trialData.Trial_Stimuli_3,
                        self.trialData.Trial_Stimuli_4,
                        self.trialData.Trial_Stimuli_5,
                        self.trialData.Trial_Stimuli_6,
                        self.trialData.Trial_Stimuli_7,
                        self.trialData.Trial_Stimuli_8,
                        self.trialData.Trial_Stimuli_9,
                        self.trialData.Trial_Stimuli_10,
                        self.trialData.Trial_Stimuli_11]

    self.trialControl = [self.trialData.Trial_Control_1,
                        self.trialData.Trial_Control_2,
                        self.trialData.Trial_Control_3,
                        self.trialData.Trial_Control_4,
                        self.trialData.Trial_Control_5,
                        self.trialData.Trial_Control_6,
                        self.trialData.Trial_Control_7,
                        self.trialData.Trial_Control_8,
                        self.trialData.Trial_Control_9,
                        self.trialData.Trial_Control_10,
                        self.trialData.Trial_Control_11]

    self.picture_display = tk.Label(self, bg="#5B9BD5")
    self.picture_display.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="nsew")

    #Get size of screen
    self.imageWidth = int(parent.winfo_width())
    self.imageHeight = int(parent.winfo_height())
    #cycle through images. resize was attempted but not implemented
    self.pictures = cycle((imageTk.PhotoImage(image.open(imagePath).resize((int(self.imageWidth),int(self.imageHeight)),image.ANTIALIAS)))for imagePath in self.trialStim)

    '''Center the image display on the frame DOESN'T WORK'''
    self.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
    self.grid_rowconfigure(2,weight=1)
    self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    self.grid_columnconfigure(2,weight=1)

    self.show_break()

def show_slides(self):
    #cycle through the images and show them
    img_object = next(self.pictures)
    #display image
    self.picture_display.config(image=img_object)
    #wait 2 seconds and display break page
    self.after(2000, self.show_break)

def show_break(self):
    #hide image
    self.picture_display.config(image='')
    #display text
    self.picture_display.config(fg="#FFFFFF",bg='#5B9BD5',font=('Arial',18),text="Please relax and take a break. The next slide will begin shortly.")
    #wait 2 seconds and display break page
    self.after(2000, self.show_slides)
```

Comment: The indentation is broken in your code.

Comment: So what exactly is it that you want to achieve? You want to have something like, Text A and Picture A display > Text A and Picture B display > Text B and Picture C display > Text B and Pictures C display.........?

Comment: rowconfigure/columnconfigure are not to "center" and image. They just tell the frame/window to automatically grow or shrink the grid row/column when the window resizes